# JsPDF, jsPDF-AutoTable wrapping row texts needed with overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to create an invoice using `jspdf-autotable`. I want to address a long address that will wrap properly while maintaining `overflow:hidden`.

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolr/b0Lmgxan/3) I added

`bodyStyles: { valign: "top" },
 styles: { overflow: "hidden", cellWidth: "wrap" },
 columnStyles: { text: { cellWidth: "auto" } },`

which merges the address text with the right table

And in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolr/8tb96urf/1/) I just kept `overflow:hidden` which keeps the gap between the two adjacent tables but crops the address text.

1. I want to keep the full address text which will wrap properly while keeping the gap like the 2nd fiddle.
2. Is is possible to align right where the columns have numerical data? like `QTY`, `Price`, `Amount`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the address to wrap probably into multiple line, you need to remove the `overflow: "hidden"` and the `cellWidth: "wrap"` styles, `"warp"` here actually means not to wrap and put it in one line only, so you need to remove both styles, you may also want to set `minCellWidth` to caption fields.

for question number 2, you can specify right align to specific columns like this `columnStyles: {2: {halign: 'right'}, 3: {halign: 'right'}}`

Comment: Thanks.
no 2 worked fine here is the fiddle but I have not found anything called caption field to add `minCelWidth`
https://jsfiddle.net/coolr/8tb96urf/8

So the problems are highlighed here about the head alignment and the text cropping issues
https://imgur.com/a/5VqWpSo

Comment: I see you didn't remove `overflow: "hidden"` still, this needs to be removed the long text will wrap.

Comment: Thanks! I have removed it and was also able to widen the column. I just need the QTY, Price, Amount headings aligned right.

Comment: For head styles you will need to define each header style with the content, in your `headRows` instead of each header being string like `qty: "QTY",` it will need to be object like this `qty: {content: "QTY", styles: {halign: 'right'}},`
Please mark the answer as accepted if your question is answered.